# How do I set a time in a google form, then limit the selections of persons to select based on the entry?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Currently, I am creating a form to list every meeting that our team has, the time, the supervisor, who attended, who did not attend, and a description.  I can include every agent with the checkbox option to run reports after the form data populates but, with all agents included, it can be very time-tasking.

Essentially, I want to be able to have set times that, when selected, will return a group of agents that can be selected in checkboxes.  For example, if I choose 7:45AM, the options to select would only include in checkboxes Joe, Sam, and Chris.  Yet, if I select 9:00AM, the agents that would be listed in the selection would be Charles, Frank, and Angie (fake names).

Is this something that is possible in forms and/or with the script editor?

Comment: are you doing this on Apps Script or Sheets API?

Comment: This is being performed in apps script?  The script editor of Google Sheets.